# Ссылка на скачивание картинкой

Tags: content, изображения, php, wordpress

Всем привет! подскажите, пжлста, как сделать ссылку на скачивание контента в Вордпрессе картинкой? Я полный нуб и только начинаю этим заниматься. поэтому разжуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="">
   <img src="путь к картинке" alt="" />
</a>
```